# Spring Error creating bean

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to run the following [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-login-example/) . I am using Spring Tool Suite and I have create, a Spring MVC Project.
I configure everything(I think). But I am getting the following exception:
[PasteBin Exception from server.](http://pastebin.com/UqJuuYKK)

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringMVCloginExample</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springWeb.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

springBeanConfiguration.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
        <bean id="loginDelegate" class="com.havistudio.delegate.LoginDelegate">
            <property name="userService" ref="userService"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="userService" class="com.havistudio.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
            <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean name="userDao" class="com.havistudio.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sprinexamples" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="kostas" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

springWeb.xml:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.havistudio" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
       </bean>
        <import resource="springBeanConfiguration.xml"/>
    </beans>
```

I am new at the Spring Framework. Thanks.

Comment: Its complaining about mysql jar missing from your class path

Comment: add the mysql.jar inside \WebContent\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: Thanks both you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception from server reads:

> Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

So add the `mysql.jar` inside `\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib`.